# When are usually the applications deadlines in United States for a Computer Sciences graduate program?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, deadlines

I’m a French student graduating in computer science this year, and I want to do my master in the United States, I want to join the US Army, but that's another story. I have to apply for a program starting Fall, 2016 at the latest in order to still have a chance to join the French Army as a commissioned officer, a second-choice job plan. I know I have to pass a the Toefl and a GRE test.

Yet, I’m absolutely new to the Anglo-Saxon system, and it seemed that most application deadlines were closed by the 8th of December.

Thus, generally speaking, what are the deadlines for applications?
Is there an official date? And last, do I still have a chance to join a United States graduate program for Fall, 2016?

Comment: Please do come back around Christmas and let us know how this story worked out.

Answer (score 4):

There are official dates, set by each program.  Most of those are in the winter prior to the autumn in which you hope to start.  Of the timelines and deadlines I'm aware of, it's too late to apply for starting fall 2016 at most schools. Especially if you haven't yet taken the TOEFL and GRE, you should be targeting next year's cycle (assuming you still want to apply then).  It takes a while to get those tests scheduled, taken, and graded, and you generally have to have scores in by the application deadline.

A quick survey of Masters' application deadlines for schools in the first page of [Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=CS%20masters%20application&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8):

- [Stanford](http://www-cs.stanford.edu/admissions/deadlines): Dec-08
- [Columbia](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/education/ms/appfaq): Feb-15 (but may accept some late)
- [Chicago](https://csmasters.uchicago.edu/page/deadlines): Feb-01 for international students
- **[Brown](https://cs.brown.edu/degrees/masters/applications/): Mar-15**
- [Carnegie Mellon](https://www.csd.cs.cmu.edu/academics/masters/admissions): Dec-15
- [Georgia Tech](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/academics/degree-programs/masters/computer-science/admissionreqs): Feb-01
- [UT Austin](http://services.cs.utexas.edu/recruit/grad/frontmatter/announcement.html): Dec-01
- [Illinois](https://cs.illinois.edu/prospective-students/graduate-students/ms-phd-programs/application-deadlines-and-steps-apply-graduat): Dec-15
- [Michigan](https://www.eecs.umich.edu/eecs/graduate/cse/apply/): Jan-15

Look for programs that are of interest to you and then check their application deadlines for a specific answer.

Comment: There are some lower-ranked programs that will look at applications well into the summer, particularly if you're not seeking funding.

Comment: Also, there could be programs with rolling admissions (in other words, no fixed deadline, admissions treated as soon as they are filed). My university is doing rolling admission for PhD studies for the sole reason that we are new and relatively unknown.

Comment: Some of those places do have rolling admissions, but even with rolling admissions there comes some time when you have to roll to the next year and change the start date offered to successful applicants.  That's the deadline in a rolling setting.

Comment: @WBT, in my university, even the start date is rolling. Not sure if any long-established university will have this leeway, though.

Comment: @svavil do you have classes on a semester schedule or something like that? Are there dates when it becomes too late to join a class in the current semester, and one who wishes to join must wait until the next semester?  Are there sequences of courses where earlier courses are prerequisites of later ones?  Are there required courses, especially if they are part of such sequences, that are not offered every semester?

Comment: @WBT I am now talking about PhD student admissions, which, in our program, are only required to take few courses. PhD students may start working on their research at any point in time. Also, we have two-month long terms, which probably makes it easier.

Comment: @svavil Yes, rolling start dates make much more sense for PhD programs that are heavy on research and light on classes.

Comment: Okay, I started my application for Brown University and I already have taken the TOEFL with a result of 92 and I'm undergoing the GRE. I found that Citadel University also still accept application. I know this is very short, I'm not use to the Amercian educational system. Thanks anyway. Anymore advises?